# The package system is broken on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: package-management

I am prompted with an error on software update in Ubuntu 22.04. How can I fix error: "trying to overwrite shared FILE which is different from other instances of package NAME". Example below:

```
trying to overwrite shared '/usr/lib/llvm-14/lib/libunwind.so.1.0',
which is different from other instances of package libunwind-14:i386
...
```

Full terminal output at the bottom of this question

```
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libunwind-14_1%3a14.0.0-1ubuntu1_i386.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libc++abi1-14_1%3a14.0.0-1ubuntu1_i386.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libc++1-14_1%3a14.0.0-1ubuntu1_i386.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Screen 1

[image]

Screen 2

[image]

Screen 3

[image]

Full output:

```
lis@lenovo:~$ sudo apt-get install -f
[sudo] password for lis: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libc++1-14:i386 libc++abi1-14:i386 libunwind-14:i386
Suggested packages:
  clang:i386
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libc++1-14:i386 libc++abi1-14:i386 libunwind-14:i386
0 upgraded, 3 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
5 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/391 kB of archives.
After this operation, 1 475 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 215160 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libunwind-14_1%3a14.0.0-1ubuntu1_i386.deb ...
Unpacking libunwind-14:i386 (1:14.0.0-1ubuntu1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libunwind-14_1%3a14.0.0-1ubuntu1_i386.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite shared '/usr/lib/llvm-14/lib/libunwind.so.1.0', which is different from other instances of package libunwind-14:i386
Preparing to unpack .../libc++abi1-14_1%3a14.0.0-1ubuntu1_i386.deb ...
Unpacking libc++abi1-14:i386 (1:14.0.0-1ubuntu1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libc++abi1-14_1%3a14.0.0-1ubuntu1_i386.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite shared '/usr/lib/llvm-14/lib/libc++abi.so.1.0', which is different from other instances of package libc++abi1-14:i386
Preparing to unpack .../libc++1-14_1%3a14.0.0-1ubuntu1_i386.deb ...
Unpacking libc++1-14:i386 (1:14.0.0-1ubuntu1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libc++1-14_1%3a14.0.0-1ubuntu1_i386.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite shared '/usr/lib/llvm-14/lib/libc++.so.1.0', which is different from other instances of package libc++1-14:i386
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libunwind-14_1%3a14.0.0-1ubuntu1_i386.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libc++abi1-14_1%3a14.0.0-1ubuntu1_i386.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libc++1-14_1%3a14.0.0-1ubuntu1_i386.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should remove the cached versions and try again because they are conflicting.

**First**, remove the cached versions:

```
sudo rm /var/cache/apt/archives/*.deb
sudo rm -R /var/cache/apt/archives/partial
```

**Next**, try again:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt -f install
sudo apt dist-upgrade
```

Please post any future errors.

---

**EDIT (see solution below):**

Each offending package is i386 version. The amd64 and i386 version of each package contains a file of the same name in the same location but the hashsum of the file is different. For these particular packages, the amd64 and i386 versions cannot coexist.

The solution is to remove the i386 version unless it is absolutely necessary to have the i386 version installed.

Just be careful and **be sure to inspect the list of packages to remove before you accept Y** after you run:

```
sudo apt remove libc++1-14:i386 libc++abi1-14:i386 libunwind-14:i386
```

**In this particular case, the OP reported that removing `libc++1-14:i386` alone solved the problem.**

Comment: Did not work. I removed all /var/cache/apt/archives/*.deb files. 
Partial directory was already empty. 
When I run `sudo apt -f install` i get this:

`Unpacking libunwind-14:i386 (1:14.0.0-1ubuntu1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libunwind-14_1%3a14.0.0-1ubuntu1_i386.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite shared '/usr/lib/llvm-14/lib/libunwind.so.1.0', which is different from other instances of package libunwind-14:i386`

Comment: try a different mirror or main server. `sudo rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*`  and `sudo apt update && sudo apt -f install`

Comment: @DevWL Is there a reason you need i386 versions installed? Sometimes these versions conflict with amd64 versions and you can't have both installed. A file of the same name is provided by both the amd64 and i386 version.

Comment: @DevWL Is your system amd64 (standard Ubuntu 64 bit), i386 (extremely unlikely 32bit) or something else like ARM? Are you using i386 to cross compile? I don't see any packages listed to autoremove but you could try `sudo apt autoremove` and if you don't need the i386 packages, I would remove the offending packages since standard methods did not resolve the issue and because conflicting files exist between the amd64 and i386 versions (the shasums are different).

Comment: @DevWL Just **be careful and be sure to inspect the list of packages to remove** before you accept `Y` after you run: `sudo apt remove libc++1-14:i386 libc++abi1-14:i386 libunwind-14:i386`

Comment: Thanks I run
sudo apt remove libc++1-14:i386 libc++abi1-14:i386 libunwind-14:i386
But it shows issue with libc++1:i386 so I did run sudo apt-get remove libc++1:i386

Comment: @DevWL I'm guessing the issue is that the other two (`libc++abi1-14:i386` and `libunwind-14:i386`) depend on `libc++1:i386`? If so, remove `libc++1:i386` first, and then remove `libc++abi1-14:i386` and `libunwind-14:i386`. If you get the original `trying to overwrite shared . . .` error from your question after removing these packages, use `sudo apt purge . . .` instead of `sudo apt remove . . .`

Comment: @DevWL Otherwise, please edit your question and add the error you get when trying to remove  `libc++1:i386` thanks.

Comment: @mchid I did not make a note of it. The purpose was to remove Ubuntu error notice on software update. Removing  libc++1:i386 solved the issue for me. So thank you very much for your help, I would not do it without your help. Regards

Comment: @mchid are you able to advise on https://askubuntu.com/questions/1442128/upgrade-attempt-shows-the-package-system-is-broken-on-ubuntu-22-04