# Upgrade attempt shows The package system is broken on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: apt, package-management, 22.04

I'm having a similar issue to what was reported at:

[The package system is broken on Ubuntu 22.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1416938/the-package-system-is-broken-on-ubuntu-22-04?newreg=a946da6c3bcb4d9793d7de8b80163fc2)

the error does not state a specific package but the following

[image]

Following the guidance from there, I tried the initial suggestion but got stuck when I ran

```
sudo apt -f install
```

I get the following

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libflashrom1 libftdi1-2 linux-image-unsigned-5.15.0-47-generic linux-modules-5.15.0-47-generic
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  linux-image-unsigned-5.15.0-47-generic
Suggested packages:
  fdutils linux-doc | linux-source-5.15.0 linux-tools linux-headers-5.15.0-47-generic linux-modules-extra-5.15.0-47-generic
The following packages will be REMOVED
  linux-image-5.15.0-47-generic
The following NEW packages will be installed
  linux-image-unsigned-5.15.0-47-generic
0 to upgrade, 1 to newly install, 1 to remove and 6 not to upgrade.
2 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 11.6 MB of archives.
After this operation, 349 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Get:1 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 linux-image-unsigned-5.15.0-47-generic amd64 5.15.0-47.51 [11.6 MB]
Fetched 11.6 MB in 1s (10.1 MB/s)                                  
ERROR couldn't connect to zsys daemon: timed out waiting for server handshake 
dpkg: linux-image-5.15.0-47-generic: dependency problems, but removing anyway as you requested:
 linux-modules-5.15.0-47-generic depends on linux-image-5.15.0-47-generic | linux-image-unsigned-5.15.0-47-generic; however:
  Package linux-image-5.15.0-47-generic is to be removed.
  Package linux-image-unsigned-5.15.0-47-generic is not installed.

dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'linux-image-5.15.0-53-generic' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
(Reading database ... 336117 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing linux-image-5.15.0-47-generic (5.15.0-47.51) ...
/etc/kernel/postrm.d/initramfs-tools:
update-initramfs: Deleting /boot/initrd.img-5.15.0-47-generic
/etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub:
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub'
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub.d/init-select.cfg'
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: vmlinuz-5.15.0-53-generic in rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_ps7599
Found initrd image: initrd.img-5.15.0-53-generic in rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_ps7599
Found linux image: vmlinuz-5.15.0-52-generic in rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_ps7599
Found initrd image: initrd.img-5.15.0-52-generic in rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_ps7599
umount: /tmp/zfsmnt.zOPd5E: target is busy.
zfs_mount_at() failed: mountpoint or dataset is busyumount: /tmp/zfsmnt.zOPd5E: target is busy.
rmdir: failed to remove '/tmp/zfsmnt.zOPd5E': Device or resource busy
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub exited with return code 1
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-5.15.0-47-generic (--remove):
 installed linux-image-5.15.0-47-generic package post-removal script subprocess returned error exit status 1
dpkg: too many errors, stopping
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-5.15.0-47-generic
Processing was halted because there were too many errors.
ZSys is adding automatic system snapshot to GRUB menu
ERROR "update-grub" returned an error: exit status 1 
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Please help, thanks

```
lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS
Release:    22.04
Codename:   jammy
```

Comment: @nobody
I think misunderstood that earlier.

`sudo apt-mark manual linux-modules-5.15.0-47-generic
linux-modules-5.15.0-47-generic set to manually installed`

got

`ERROR couldn't connect to zsys daemon: timed out waiting for server handshake 
dpkg: linux-image-5.15.0-47-generic: dependency problems, but removing anyway as you requested:
 linux-modules-5.15.0-47-generic depends on linux-image-5.15.0-47-generic | linux-image-unsigned-5.15.0-47-generic; however:
  Package linux-image-5.15.0-47-generic is to be remov
  Package linux-image-unsigned-5.15.0-47-generic is not installed.`

Comment: also

`Found initrd image: initrd.img-5.15.0-52-generic in rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_ps7599
umount: /tmp/zfsmnt.eKhwTH: target is busy.
zfs_mount_at() failed: mountpoint or dataset is busyumount: /tmp/zfsmnt.eKhwTH: target is busy.
rmdir: failed to remove '/tmp/zfsmnt.eKhwTH': Device or resource busy
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub exited with return code 1`

Comment: If you are running Docker containers on this system, see https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/zsys/+bug/1882090 for one possible problem/solution.

Comment: Oh I didn't scroll enough on mobile. Sorry.

Comment: First, what are you trying to do and why? Also, why are there 6 packages not to upgrade?